# Material-UI Set Class Property From State

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, reactn

I have a component like below.  I want to be able to use a value from the state such as `[opacity, setOpacity] = useGlobal('opacity')` and have the opacity be the value for `tileBody` background.  What would be the best way to go about this?

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import {CardContent, fade, Hidden} from "@material-ui/core";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import { useGlobal, setGlobal, useDispatch } from 'reactn';

/*
options = {
    ...other options,
    tileTransparencyValue: 75,
*/


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    tile: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    tileHeader:  {
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.grey[800], 0.7),
    },
    tileBody: {
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.grey[800], tileTransparencyValue/100),
    },
}));


export default function DashTile(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useGlobal('options');
    const {title, content} = props;
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
            <Card className={classes.tile}>
                <CardContent className={classes.tileHeader}>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{title}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardContent className={classes.tileBody}>
                    <Typography variant="content">{content}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass props to your styles like this:

```
export default function DashTile(props) {
    const [options, setOptions] = useGlobal('options');
    const [opacity, setOpacity] = useGlobal('opacity')
    const {title, content} = props;
    const classes = useStyles({opacity})

    return (
        <Grid item lg={4} xs={12}>
            <Card className={classes.tile}>
                <CardContent className={classes.tileHeader}>
                    <Typography variant="h5">{title}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardContent className={classes.tileBody}>
                    <Typography variant="content">{content}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Then you can retrive the props inside the styles like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    tile: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    tileHeader:  {
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.grey[800], 0.7),
    },
    tileBody: {
        backgroundColor: ({opacity}) => fade(theme.palette.grey[800], opacity)
    },
}));
```

Reference: [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook)

Comment: I can only initialize the `useStyles` outside the class, but can only call `useGlobal` inside the class.  When I put the `useGlobal` call above the styles, I get the error `> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`.  I added my full code to the question as well.

Comment: You pass the props to the useStyles function call which happens inside the component. I updated the code for better visualization.

Comment: You didn't specify how to access props in the styles.  I found it in the material-ui documentation.  If you add it to your answer, I'll mask yours as correct.  ```tileBody: props => ({
        backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.grey[800], props.opacity/100),
    }),```

Comment: But it's right there, the only difference is that I placed the hook function directly in the backgroundColor attribute and deconstructed the props to get opacity directly. Both syntax should work.

Comment: `backgroundColor: ({opacity}) => fade(theme.palette.grey[800], opacity)`